# How to attach SBT classes to Intellij Idea?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, sbt-idea

I have probably a silly problem. I would like to write SBT build script (Build.scala) in IntelliJ Idea but IDE does not recognize SBT classes (Build, Project, etc.). I attached sbt-launch.jar to the project but it didn't change anything since sbt-launch.jar does not contain these classes. What should I do to make this work?

Comment: It should be fine now with the recent IntelliJ IDEA 13.x as [it comes with the SBT support](http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2013/11/18/built-in-sbt-support-in-intellij-idea-13/).

Answer (score 1):

Use [sbt-idea plugin](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea)

Comment: He is asking what jar files he needs to reference to edit a SBT *.scala build file - Not, how to build a SBT project in Intellij. I'm trying to get the same thing working.

Comment: Did you try it? This plugin is a simplest way to include all sbt jars

Comment: I use that plugin. I think you are confusing what he wants to do. He wants code completion/validation of a *Project.scala file.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, on a Linux system with ZSH installed, I've been using the following to elucidate class file locations.... nasty, but better than nothing

```
zsh

setopt extendedglob

for i ( /home/work/.sbt/boot/scala-2.9.2/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.12.0/*(.) ); do for j ( $(zipinfo -1 $i) ) ; do echo $i $j ; done ; done | grep Task
```

Using the above, I discovered that Task is defined in:

```
/home/work/.sbt/boot/scala-2.9.2/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.12.0/task-system-0.12.0.jar
```

I guess we will need to do this for ever referenced class.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to attach is the SBT libraries which is downloaded not the sbt launcher. SBT launcher jar downloads SBT and Scala into a different directory.

I would also suggest using sbt-idea plugin instead of trying to setup the project yourself. But If you still want to do it by yourself then add the following jar files to your intellij module:

```
<boot dir>/scala-2.9.1/org.scala-tools.sbt/sbt/0.11.2/*.jar
<boot dir>/scala-2.9.1/lib/*.jar
```

The boot dir is different depending on how you installed sbt. If you installed from yum or some other standard way your boot directory will be ~/.sbt/boot.